# How to append the text which is given in edittext to listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

How to set the data of edittext to listview which are given dynamically into the edittext.What i am doing is giving the values into edittext one after the after,so that after giving one value,we must clear the edittext.For that purpose,what i want to do is what ever values are entered into edittext must be appended

Answer (score 0):

Like this...

First have your layout such as..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity do this..

```
private ListView lv1;

private String lv_arr[]={"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"}; //Text that goes into the listview rows"Have your edit text text's added instead of what i put as example
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
  // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.
  lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the edit text value

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String text=ed.getText();
```

Create a custom listAdapter

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context;
    private String[] values;
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.common, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          LinearLayout v = new LinearLayout(AppStarter.this);
          v.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
          TextView listText = new TextView(AppStarter.this);
          listText.setText(text);      //the one you got from the edittext
          return v;
        }
}
```

then set the listAdapter to `setListAdapter(myListAdapterObject)` or if you have created a ListView and adding your list into it use `listViewObject.setAdapter(myListAdapterObject)`
Hope this helps.... cheers :)